# IE9 CSS3 Linear Gradients: Why does PIE CSS Gradients not work in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, css3pie

From my understanding, IE9 does not support gradients? So why does PIE CSS Gradients not work in IE9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for linear-gradient in IE9 in CSS3 PIE is currently under development. You can get a development build with initial support at http://css3pie.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=933 -- testing and feedback are appreciated.

This IE9 support has lagged behind because, since IE9 supports most of the CSS3 features natively, the VML approach used in IE6-8 is not suitable and has had to be rewritten using SVG. It's a similar story for border-image support which is also under current development.