# CSS3Pie v1.0 - No gradients in IE9, works in IE8

Tags: html, css, css3pie

I am trying to get linear gradients to work with CSS3Pie (v1.0) and IE9.

Strangely the demo works on the [CSS3Pie site](http://css3pie.com/) with IE9, but using the same CSS used on the demo does not work on my site. It works with IE8, so I know that PIE is working and in the correct location (to test, it stops working if I comment out `behavior: url(/css/PIE.htc);`).

Here is the CSS I am using:

```
.test {
padding: 20px;
text-align: center;
width: 200px;
height:100px;
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius: 8px;
-webkit-box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
-moz-box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
background: #FF7777;
position:relative;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#FF7777), to(#c40808));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FF7777, #c40808);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FF7777, #c40808);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#FF7777, #c40808);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#FF7777, #c40808);
background: linear-gradient(#FF7777, #c40808);
-pie-background: linear-gradient(#FF7777, #c40808);
behavior: url(/css/PIE.htc);
}
```

[image]

I'd prefer not to use IE filters, since the demo seems to work without them.

I've already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500956/ie9-css3-linear-gradients-why-does-pie-css-gradients-not-work-in-ie9), but since the demo works, and this question is about a year old, and PIE is now on version 1.0 that I must be doing something wrong.

Any idea on where to go from here?

Comment: try using absolute path (with `http://localhost/` etc.) and see if it changes anything

Comment: I find that using the javascript implementation for PIE works better than using the HTC implementation.  But I have only used PIE for border radius support.

Comment: Teddy: This is a high-volume public site, so re-rendering after page load is a bit of a concern, unfortunately.

Comment: I know i had this issue with IE9 too with an earlier version of PIE. I mixed in some filters though. Try omitting the `-pie-background`, it's not necessary and perhaps this causes the issue.

Comment: Christoph: Sorry, no luck with that suggestion. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Failure in IE9 is usually due to an incorrect content-type header. Other IE versions have this issue as well but IE9 seems to be more strict about it. See http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/#content-type for details.

Comment: It's currenty being served as: /css/PIE.htc GET 200 text/html 8.26 KB. I'll give your suggestion a try.

Comment: lojjic: just wondering if the PHP header method has any disadvantages. Is it slower to load?

Comment: It shouldn't be slower to load per se, but it may not be cached the same as a static resource.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a big headache because even with the correct content-type header (text/x-component), the linear-gradient wasn't working on IE9.

Upgrading to PIE 2.0 solved the issue.

http://css3pie.com/2013/01/28/pie-2-0-beta-1-released

(Same awnser I gave in this question: [linear-gradient using CSS3 PIE in IE9 not working, IE8 does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457519/linear-gradient-using-css3-pie-in-ie9-not-working-ie8-does/15796651#15796651))